# Cannot assign value of type '(UIImage?, PHAsset?)' to type UIImage? Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I updated to XCode 7.3 -  swift 2.2 and I received a compile time error as mentioned in the title. It had no issues in swift 2.1. As per basics of swift, '?' variables can be compared to nil. I googled for possible solutions, but could not find the appropriate solution. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem was not in swift update but in ALCameraViewController update. Now it takes completion with two parameters

```
public typealias CameraViewCompletion = (UIImage?, PHAsset?) -> Void
```

So you need to change this

```
(image) -> Void in ...
```

to this

```
(image, asset) -> Void in ...
```

Actually now in your code Swift treats image as tuple of two values so also you can change all calls to **image** in your code with calls to **image.0** that will address first closure parameter that is your UIImage?